# Python and SQLite3: how to write less values than a table has colums

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am using Python3 and SQLite3.  I have a table with 6 columns, but I am only inserting values to 4 of the columns.

execute("INSERT INTO  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [list_name])

The error I get:
ERROR: table blacklisted_ips has 6 columns but 4 values were supplied

list_name = [(24, 'somestring', '2018/05/06', '2018-05-13 10:16:34'), (24, 'somestring', '2018/05/06', '2018-05-13 10:16:34')]

So the question is how do I write to only 4 of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

[Specify the columns you care about.](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO sometable
  (foo, bar, baz, quux)
  VALUES
  (42, 420, 3.14, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  The values are in a list, though. Will it still work?

Answer (score 1):

[The SQLite page for INSERT operation](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) specifies:

```
If a column-name list is specified, then the number of values in each
term of the VALUE list must match the number of specified columns.
Each of the named columns of the new row is populated with the
results of evaluating the corresponding VALUES expression.
```

What you want would be:

```
INSERT INTO blacklisted_ips (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```